# White resin or powder on conifer needles

Tags: botany, ecology

I often notice that certain conifers often have a whitish powder on what seems to be their youngest needles, giving them a blue green tint. Does anyone know what this is? Is it something excreted by the trees themselves, is it a yeast or some other endophytic microorganism? Very curious and unfortunately I don't have a microscope.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is actually crystallized sap which formed on and around the bud as the bud opened up and new leafs emerged.

Note that some coniferous trees have a powdery coating as part of the leaf itself, continuing on throughout the life of the leaf. [Blue spruce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_spruce) is a good example of this, as its dark green needles appear blue/gray due to a waxy coating the needles. This wax can be easily scraped off the leaf.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In the case of blue spruce, does the powder diminish overtime, for example on shaded needles that receive less sunlight?

Comment: Great question @DezmondGoff. I can confirm that conifers with powdery or waxy needles will have patches with significantly more or less coating, but I don't know what the causes of that are (whether it's time, sunlight, [types of leaf](http://www.saps.org.uk/saps-associates/browse-q-and-a/158-q-a-a-what-is-the-physical-difference-between-plants-that-grow-in-the-direct-sunlight-and-those-that-grow-in-the-shade)).